# If $(e_n)_{n∈ℕ}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$ and $X:Ω→H$ is independent of $\mathcal F$, then $⟨X,e_m⟩_H⟨X,e_n⟩_H$ is independent of $\mathcal F$

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Let

- $H$ be a separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space
- $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal A$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$
- $X:\Omega\to H$ be measurable with respect to $\mathcal A$-$\mathcal B(H)$ and independent of $\mathcal F$

We know that the product of two real-valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ which are both independent of $\mathcal F$, doesn't need to be independent of $\mathcal F$. The reason is that if $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ are $\sigma$-algebras on $\Omega$ which are both independent of $\mathcal F$, we cannot conclude that $\sigma(\mathcal G\cup\mathcal H)$ is independent of $\mathcal F$.

> However, in the situation described above, are we able to show that $\langle X,e_m\rangle_H\langle X,e_n\rangle_H$ is independent of $\mathcal F$ for all $m,n\in\mathbb N?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$X_n:=\langle X,e_n\rangle_H\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$ and $$\mathcal G:=\sigma\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\sigma(X_n)\right)\;.$$

> **Claim 1** $\:\:\:$ $\sigma(X)=\mathcal G$

- $X_n$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable for all $n\in\mathbb N$ $\Rightarrow$ $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\sigma(X_n)\subseteq\sigma(X)$$ and hence $$\sigma(X)\supseteq\mathcal G$$ by monoticity of the $\sigma$-operator
- On the other hand, $X_n$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and hence $$X=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}X_ne_n$$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable

> **Claim 2** $\:\:\:$ Let $m,n\in\mathbb N$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma(X_m,X_n)$ is independent of $\mathcal F$

- Since $$\sigma(X_m)\cup\sigma(X_n)\subseteq\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}\sigma(X_k)\;,$$ we obtain $$\sigma(X_m,X_n)=\sigma\left(\sigma(X_m)\cup\sigma(X_n)\right)\subseteq\mathcal G=\sigma(X)$$ by monoticity of the $\sigma$-operator and (*Claim 1*)
- Now, $f_m$ and $f_n$ are $\sigma(X_m,X_n)$-measurable and hence $f_mf_n$ is $\sigma(X_m,X_n)$-measurable too $\Rightarrow$ $$\sigma(f_mf_n)\subseteq\sigma(f_m,f_n)$$